# Can I use Dashcode to develop an application that can be sold in the app store?

Tags: iphone, app-store, dashcode

Can I use Dashcode to develop an application that can be sold in the app store?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Dashcode is more for creating webapps. To create an app for the App Store, you must compile it with the iPhone SDK, and for that you need to use Xcode. Furthermore, Dashcode is predominantly JavaScript-based, whereas iPhone apps must be written in Objective-C.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used DashCode, but since you can call up the browser from Objective-C, you should be able to use whatever HTML/CSS/JavaScript solutions work in Mobile Safari. Check out iui, xui, and jQTouch as well.

Some apps lend themselves to the browser solution, and some don't. Unless you use something like PhoneGap, it's quite a lot of glue work to get at the iPhone's special features with JavaScript.

Comment: I would say this is a qualified yes.  I've deployed apps using phonegap, but some claim that apple will ban it, for some unclear reason.  Regardless, you will run into a number of app specific issues, such as stopping scrolling, slow button responses, etc.  These issues are mostly addressable, but the laundry list can be quite long.